# Proof About Triangle Vertices and Area

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, triangles

Please bear with me as this is my first ever post on here (although certainly not my first time here).  I was wondering if anybody could help me get started on the following question:

Consider triangles in the plane with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$, where $a, b, x$ and $y$ are integers.
Characterize, with proof, the integers $a$ and $b$ for which all such triangles that have $(a,b)$ as a vertex, has an area that is a positive integer.

I looked all over Math SE for a related question, but couldn't find anything (if there is a related question please correct me on this).  I'm just hoping one of you kind souls would be willing to give me a hint as to where begin with this particular proof.  From what I've seen, a question like this is fairly elementary as far as proofs go, but I am stuck nonetheless.  This question isn't from any of my texts (the class is Intro to Abstract Algebra & Number Theory), but rather a question the professor wrote up himself.  Like I said, I just need some help starting this guy off.  Usually starting is the hardest part for me.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: 0,0 to x,y makes a line.  A perpendicular will have slope -y/x.  So you want 1/2 the line 0,0 to x,y times the altitude from the line to a,b is an interval.

Comment: I'd recommend using [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem).  The area of the triangle is the number of lattice points in the interior (always an integer)  plus half the number of lattice points on the sides minus 1.  All that matters for your question is the number of lattice points on the sides and they can be counted via the $\gcd$.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  I'll give them a try!